# how to copy locked files ( Device or resource busy error) on windows xp without admin permissions

Tags: windows, filesystems, ntfs

Is there is any way I can copy locked files on windows xp machine without having admin rights? I used unloker tool its great but needs admin rights to install and run. how it could be done in some programming language like perl/shell/c c++ etc. or if there exists some workaround for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [Hobocopy](http://alt.pluralsight.com/wiki/default.aspx/Craig/HoboCopy.html). It uses the volume shadowing service to create a "snapshot" and then copies that snapshot. Because HoboCopy copies from a VSS snapshot, it is able copy even files that are in locked by some other program.